# O que é isto de StringBuffer ser sincronizado ? Qual a vantagem perante StringBuilder?

Tags: java

Sei que a diferença entre stringBuffer e stringBuilder, é que um é sincronizado e outro não, e que ambos representam strings que podem ser alteradas, mas o que é que sincronizado quer dizer na prática?

Comment: Droga, estava com uma resposta quase pronta quando isso foi fechado.

Comment: @bigown Não é bem uma duplicata. Esta pergunta é acerca da sincronização, coisa que a outra não fala. A outra pergunta é acerca do espaço extra que é alocado no `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder` para melhorar o desempenho. A questão da sincronização é abordada apenas como um ponto extra na resposta do utluiz - as demais três respostas não falam nada sobre isso.

Comment: Mas a resposta está lá, não está?

Comment: @bigown Bem, não vou votar para reabrir de qualquer forma. Mas se não fosse a resposta do utluiz, eu certamente faria isso.

Comment: Sim, se não tivesse a resposta dele, não estaria respondido. Se uma pesquisa tivesse sido feita com os dois nomes aquela resposta teria sido achada e a pergunta nem teria sido postada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa se a resposta acrescenta algo, posta lá mesmo que seja só como complemento.

Answer (score 0):

**StringBuilder vs StringBuffer**

Ambos são bem mais rápidos para concatenação de valores do que a String comum e fazem exatamente a mesma função. A principal diferença é que o StringBuffer é sincronizado, enquanto que o outro não. Assim, você garante a consistência do seu código quando há diversas threads lendo ou modificando a mesma String. Para esses casos, o ideal é usar o StringBuffer.

Porém o StringBuilder ainda é mais rápido do que o StringBuffer.

Fonte: http://www.devmedia.com.br/diferencas-entre-string-stringbuilder-e-stringbuffer-em-java/29865

Comment: A sua resposta diz o que ele já colocou na pergunta.

Comment: Assim, você garante a consistência do seu código quando há diversas threads lendo ou modificando a mesma String. Para esses casos, o ideal é usar o StringBuffer.